# Form Control value not retrieved for a FormArray while using Reactive Forms

Tags: angular6

I have created a form using reactive form approach. I'm creating a formGroup with 2 formControls on each button click.
On Submitting the form, I'm trying to get the values of the FormGroup which is a FormArray, but the value is not retrieved.

HTML code where I loop through the controls and create the needed formControls

```
<div class="row" formArrayName="ingredients">
          <div class="col-md-12" >


            <div class="row" 
              *ngFor="let ingredientControl of 
               recipeForm.get('ingredients').controls; 
               let index = index"

              [formGroupName]="index"
              style="margin-top: 10px;"
              >
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  formControlName="ingredientName"
                  >
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="number"
                class="form-control"
                formControlName="ingredientAmount"
                >
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"
                (click)="onDeleteIngredient(index)"> X 
              </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
```

.ts file where I try to get the FormControl values

I submit the form in the template using (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"

```
onSubmit(){

   const newRecipe = new RecipeModel(
      this.recipeForm.value['recipeName'],
      this.recipeForm.value['imagePath'],
      this.recipeForm.value['description'],
      this.recipeForm.value['ingredients'],

    );
    this.recipeService.addNewRecipe(newRecipe);
  }
```

Here, `this.recipeForm.value['ingredients']` is returning empty. But while trying to print the FormArray value, the control has value.

I expect the form to return the ingredientName and ingredientAmount so that I can pass the value to the service method. But I'm not getting the value form the form.